# How to export activity in ACT! To Hubspot

Tags: database, hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-api, act

There is a database of people in ACT!, there are a lot of them (21k), when importing into HubSpot, the Activity pane doesn't populate.[pic ACT!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSc9H.png)[pic hubspot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oa3S1.png)
I'd be very happy if you could help with the code a little bit. Peace out

I tried exporting the base, it exports without Activity, I think I'll try via API to pull it out, and add Activity to Notes

```
`const fetch = require('node-fetch'); // Для Node.js

async function loadActivitiesFromAct() {
    const actApiUrl = '';
    const apiKey = '';

    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${actApiUrl}/activities`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`
            }
        });
        if (response.ok) {
            return await response.json();
        } else {
            console.error(`Failed to load activities from ACT! API: ${response.statusText}`);
            return null;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error loading activities from ACT! API: ${error}`);
        return null;
    }
}

async function createNoteActivityInHubSpot(noteContent) {
    const hubspotApiKey = '';
    const hubspotApiUrl = '';

    const data = {
        engagement: {
            active: true,
            ownerId: 1,
            type: 'NOTE'
        },
        associations: {
        },
        metadata: {
            body: noteContent
        }
    };

    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${hubspotApiUrl}?hapikey=${hubspotApiKey}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('Note activity created successfully in HubSpot!');
        } else {
            console.error(`Failed to create note activity in HubSpot: ${response.statusText}`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error creating note activity in HubSpot: ${error}`);
    }
}

async function importActivitiesFromActToHubSpot() {
    const activities = await loadActivitiesFromAct();
    if (activities) {
        activities.forEach(activity => {
            const noteContent = `Activity from ACT!:\n${JSON.stringify(activity)}`;
            createNoteActivityInHubSpot(noteContent);
        });
    }
}

importActivitiesFromActToHubSpot();
`
```